# Show image on top of the background color in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap and have a layout similar to this:

```
<div class="container stamp">
    <div class="row">
          Some header text
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color:black">
          More header text here
    </div>
    <div class="row">
          More text
    </div>
</div>
```

I've set the background image that overlaps all the three rows

```
.stamp {
  background-image: url('img/hugestamp.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: left top;
}
```

The `hugestamp.gif` spans across all the three rows but the second row has the background color of black, so part of the image is cut off. How do I make the image show up on top of the background color (maybe `z-index`?) on the 2nd row?

**EDIT: I cannot make the colored row transparent. I am trying to achieve the styling here:**

[image]

In the image, you can see the 3 rows and how the image is shown on top of the colored row

Comment: Remove the inline style background-color: black. You can't have the background cover an inline style in the div inside it; and why would you want to?

Comment: It is not possible to do without some tinkering with background-position. See my solution below.

Comment: Can you please accept the correct answer?

Comment: @DotnetDude do you intend to change your html layout? or do it by using css only?

Answer (score 5):

**Try this code**

Image over colored row

```css
.stamp {
    background-image: url('http://imgh.us/new-google-logo-knockoff.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -69px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
  position:relative
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
          Some header text
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color:black">
           More header text here
    </div>
    <div class="row">
          More text
    </div>
    <div class="stamp"></div>
</div>
```

Image over colored row containing text

```css
.stamp {
    background-image: url('http://imgh.us/new-google-logo-knockoff.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -69px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 15;
}
.container{
  position:relative
}
.row:nth-child(2):after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: -20;
}
.row:nth-child(2) {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
          Some header text
    </div>
    <div class="row">
           More header text here
    </div>
    <div class="row">
          More text
    </div>
    <div class="stamp"></div>
</div>
```

Image over colored row and below text

```css
.stamp {
    background-image: url('http://imgh.us/new-google-logo-knockoff.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -69px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -10;
}
.container{
  position:relative
}
.row:nth-child(2):after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: -20;
}
.row:nth-child(2) {
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
          Some header text
    </div>
    <div class="row">
           More header text here
    </div>
    <div class="row">
          More text
    </div>
    <div class="stamp"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see edit for more details on what I am trying to acheive

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using inline css. You can do it by using transparent background color.
The transparency can be regulated by changing the last number of background-color property--

```
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, *0.4*);
```

**Example snippet**

```css
.stamp {
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: left top;
}
#blck {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container stamp">
  <div class="row">
    Some header text
  </div>
  <div id="blck" class="row">
    More header text here
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    More text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot use the transparency option. Please see Edit

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```css
.container {
  background: #EBEBEB;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row {
  background: white;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/T/j/X/6/y/m/grey-approved-stamp-hi.png);
  background-position: left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#top {
  padding: 10px;
}

#second {
  background-position: left calc(-180px + 20px + 20px); 
  /* left (-image height + middle row height + paddings) */
}

#third {
  background-position: left calc(-180px - 30px); 
  /* left (-image height + middle row height + paddings) */
}
```

```html
<div class="container stamp">
    <div id = "first" class="row">
          Some header text
    </div>
    <div id = "second" class="row" style="background-color:#3d3d3d; color: white; min-height: 50px;margin-bottom:0px;">
          More header text here
    </div>
    <div id = "third" class="row">
          More text
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the image on TOP of the colored row. Please see a sample of the design I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for your issue. Below i have added 2 inline style to your background color

```
<div class="container stamp">
<div class="row">
      Some header text
</div>
<div class="row" style="background-color:black;z-index: -1;position: relative;">
      More header text here
</div>
<div class="row">
      More text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If want the text over the image and the background-color below it then its impossible because its a single component.

if want that row transparent just remove the inline css part

explain more the result you want to get please

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't want to change* your HTML layout and do this just by altering *css*, you can set background image to pseudo elements `:before` of `.stamp` instead.

```css
.stamp:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/300);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container stamp">
    <div class="row">
          Some header text
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color:black">
          More header text here
    </div>
    <div class="row">
          More text
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).